# Analytical approach to a quadratics problem

Tags: functions, logic, quadratics

I'm a bit rusty on functions and this exercise got me thinking quite a bit.

> The function $y=x$ is tangent to the graph of a certain $g$ function in $x=0$.
>
> Function $g$ can be defined as:

- A) $g(x)=x^2+x$
- B) $g(x)=x^2+x+1$
- C) $g(x)=x^2+2x$
- D) $g(x)=x^2+2x+1$

---

Solving the problem graphically I know the only possible answer is A but how would I approach it from an analytical view?

I know that if $y=x$ and that if the function is tanget at $x=0$, $g(0)=0$. On that criteria I can fit both A and C since $g(0)=1$ for B and D.

What am I missing from the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach so far is correct. Yet remember that $y = x$ is tangential to $g(x)$ in $x = 0$. This means that $g'(0) = 1$, since the slope of $y = x$ is $1$ for all $x$. As such, only option A) can be correct, for only A) fulfills the condition $g'(0) = 1$ (of A) and C), having already ruled out B) and D) with $g(0) = 0$)

Comment: But for example I know (from the graph) that the $y=x$ is a secant line on option C. Are you sugesting that $g'(0)$ of A and C are different?

Comment: Yes they are! In C) $g'(0) = 2$, which cannot be correct since $y = x$ is supposed to be tangential to $g(x)$ in $x = 0$, so $g'(0)$ needs to be $= 1$.

Comment: Aw. I got it the logic now! :) Thanks :D

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Thanks for the editing, I didn't know how to make my answers look like taken from LaTex until now!

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of a function at a point is equal to the slope of the tangent at that point. Since the slope of $y=x$ is $1$ you have to check which function satisfies $g'(0)=1$ (together with $g(0)=0,$ of course).